# Fedora 30 and OpenJDK 1.8.0_212: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, fedora

I do not understand why my Fedora 30 64 bit with 12 GB of RAM has problems in creating more than 10.000 threads with a Java 8 application.

I need to create a lot of Threads because the Java application is a simulator and I cannot change anything in the implementation of the Java code.

I use a 64 bit of OpenJDK limiting the size of the stack for threads with "Xss" option:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)


java  -Xmx3500m -Xss228k -jar Uni.jar
```

I tried to understand why the Fedora Linux OS does not allocate more than 10.000 threads but nothing. Any parameter seems correct and over the 10k threshold.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47765
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 47765
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
95530
```

I looked at many post here but any proposed solution does not work and I suppose it could be related to Fedora 30 or the JVM version I use.

Any hint?

===== EDIT ====

Java code is very simple because I have:

```
new Thread()
{
 ...
}
```

The same code works fine in Windows 10!

Fedora Linux memory when it reaches the 10.000 threads and raises the error is about 1,5GB of memory.

===== EDIT ====

I've simulated the same amount of threads with a simple C program that allocates 12K threads on this Fedora linux machine and after 10K I have the error "Resource temporarily unavailable".

So the problem is not related with Java, but to the Linux settings.

Comment: Check the ulimit for the user you are using to run the Java program. Something like this

ulimit -u

Comment: Also, are you sure you can't create threads because of the threads limit? Maybe you need more memory. Your max is set to 800m, sounds like is not that much for 10k of threads.

Comment: I wrote the "ulimit -a" output, ulimit -u for the user is 47765

Comment: There was a mistake the heap memory is not 800m but 3500m. I edited the post.

Comment: Sorry. I was not the one who voted down.

Comment: What kind of logic is your code doing?

Comment: Try removing the xss limit. Your threads may need more memory

Comment: new Thread() { ... }. It's so simple. It is not a question of what I do, but why the OS doesn't allow Java app to allocat more threads. Removing the Xss option doesn't change anything.

Comment: Any progress? Did you check if Fedora is really taking all the physical memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194654/discussion-between-robob-and-perimosh).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming per se